# Polyglossia and Biblatex - Changing local variables

Tags: biblatex, polyglossia

I m using Biblatex with polyglossia and although I set german as my default language, the bibliography shortcuts are still in english.
Here is a minimal working example:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{literatur.bib}

@article{Grothendieck,
author = {Grothendieck, A.},
title = {Sur quelques points d'algebre homologique, I},
language = {fr},
journal = {Tohoku Mathematical Journal},
volume = {9},
year = {1957},
pages = {119-221},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[babelshorthands]{polyglossia} 
\setdefaultlanguage[spelling=new,latesthyphen=true]{german} 
\usepackage[style=alphabetic,backend=biber,maxnames=5,maxalphanames=5,backref=true,backrefstyle=two+]{biblatex}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{%
 backrefpage = {zit. auf S.},
 backrefpages = {zit. auf S.},
 }
 \bibliography{literatur}

\begin{document}
This is a citation of \cite{Grothendieck}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

With this I get "pp." instead of "S." and "cit. on p." instead of "zit. auf S.". How can I fix that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Joseph Wright of the biblatex team has just worked out why the polyglossia support didn't work properly. I have just incorporated his fix into the biblatex 2.8 DEV version on SF if you would like to try it (and leave a comment on the github issue for this - https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/69)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`biblatex` has removed the support for polyglossia (probably because of a bug which appeared some time ago). Either use `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}` (it will work fine with XeLaTeX/luaLaTeX), or use `language=german` in the options of `biblatex`.