# Passing language=british to biblatex-chicago with polyglossia

Tags: biblatex, polyglossia

This question is similar to [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132726/polyglossia-and-biblatex-changing-local-variables), except the crux here is `biblatex-chicago`.

I understand it's been a little [rough](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/69) building `polyglossia` support for `biblatex`. Thus far, `biblatex-chicago` has been tested for `babel` instead.

To achieve British localization in `biblatex-chicago`, the manual says to load `babel` with the option `british`. When I instead use `polyglossia` and `\setmainlanguage[variant=british]{english}`, however, it loads `cms-american.lbx`, in effect the same situation noted in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132726/polyglossia-and-biblatex-changing-local-variables). In [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132726/polyglossia-and-biblatex-changing-local-variables/132731#132731) to that question, one of the solutions is to manually pass (in that case) `language=ngerman` to `biblatex`. Accordingly, the option `language=british` works for my purposes with `biblatex`. If this option is passed to `biblatex-chicago`, however, something seems to go amiss in the loading of the localization file, as all bibliography strings remain undefined:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=british]{csquotes}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage[notes,language=british]{biblatex-chicago}

\setdefaultlanguage[variant=british]{english}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Cardo}
\begin{filecontents}{book.bib}
@online{key1,
   title = {Stack Exchange},
   url = {http://www.stackexchange.com},
   urldate = {2014-09-16}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{book.bib}

\begin{document}

See date formatting in footnote below.\autocite{key1}

\end{document}
```

Warnings returned:

```
Package biblatex Warning: Bibliography string 'urlseen' undefined
(biblatex)                at entry 'key1' on input line 21.

Package biblatex Warning: Bibliography string 'september' undefined
(biblatex)                at entry 'key1' on input line 21.
```

Output:

[image: Undefined strings]
<sub>(source: [langeslag.org](http://langeslag.org/images/sx/undefinedstrings.png))</sub>

If I load `ngerman` instead it actually works, though obviously with the wrong localization. This suggests that `british` fails to be tied to a localization file.

I can think of a couple of workarounds:

1. Opt for `biblatex` over `biblatex-chicago` and copy the relevant contents of `biblatex-chicago.sty` into my own preamble (as well as importing the contents of `biblatex-chicago`'s `cms-british.lbx` somehow -- what's the elegant way of doing this?);
2. Swap out `polyglossia` in favour of `babel`. Note that my document contains over a dozen European languages.

But what's the correct way of actually telling `biblatex-chicago` to load the localization from its own `cms-british.lbx`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make `biblatex-chicago` into thinking that the language is indeed `british`:

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@online{key1,
   title = {Stack Exchange},
   url = {http://www.stackexchange.com},
   urldate = {2014-09-16}
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=british]{csquotes}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[variant=british]{english}

\let\keptlanguagename\languagename
\def\languagename{british}
\usepackage[notes,language=british]{biblatex-chicago}
\let\languagename\keptlanguagename

\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Cardo}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

See date formatting in footnote below.\autocite{key1}

\end{document}
```

Proper support of `polyglossia` would require changing `biblatex-chicago.sty`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Afaik, the `polyglossia` definition of the UK variant is

```
\setdefaultlanguage[variant=uk]{english}
```

so try changing the line

```
\setdefaultlanguage[variant=british]{english}
```

Hope it helps! Jigdrel